# Error instantiating Cucumber table to object

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm having some trouble getting datatables to map to a type in Cucumber.
Cucumber expects pojos to be co-located with the stepdefs. But what if it is in another module? How would I do the mapping? Is there a line I can add to my runner?

```
Given an appointment
    |poid|advisorCrewId|appointmentType|
    |1234|036264|wxyz|
When blah blah
Then blah blah
```

And I'm using a type I've already got laying around

```
public class Appointment implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1456832796215683035L;

        private Integer poid;

        private String advisorCrewId;

        private String appointmentType;

        public Appointment(Integer poid, String advisorCrewId, String appointmentType) {
            this.poid = poid;
            this.advisorCrewId = advisorCrewId;
            this.appointmentType = appointmentType;
        }

        public Integer getPoid() {
            return poid;
        }

        public String getAdvisorCrewId() {
            return advisorCrewId;
        }

        public String getAppointmentType() {
            return appointmentType;
        }

    }
```

But when I try to access it in Cucumber like this

```
@Given("^an appointment$")
    public void method_name(List<Appointment> appointments) {
        this.appointments = appointments;
        poid = appointments.get(0).getPoid();
    }
```

I get this error. I thought that in order to get a datatable to match a type, you just had to have the member variables match up. Is there another step I'm missing?

```
 cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot construct com.blahblah.Appointment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a maven issue. It was trying to instantiate an Interface, not a class and that's why it was throwing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you get a smaller example to work? It sounds strange to me that the datatype you are using should have to be co-located with the steps. As long as the type is available on the classpath, it should work as far as I can understand at the moment.

At the same time, have understood that the xstream package behaves unexpected in some situations and that it might be replaced in an upcoming version of Cucumber.

See if you can get this sample to work, http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2014/06/30/cucumber-data-tables

If you can get it to work, move the datatype used to another package and see it that move alone breaks it.

Comment: So this is where I sheepishly admit that I was actually just having a maven problem, Cucumber was working fine. What do I do at this point - delete the question? Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: You keep the answer for anyone else having a similar problem. Possible with an edit describing what your Maven problem was. It is all about sharing and helping.